# C# FileSystemWatcher Events Not Firing

Tags: c#, event-handling, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to implement a `FileSystemWatcher`.  However, my OnChange event handler is never getting called.  The watcher is supposed to be monitoring a log file that is being updated by another thread in the process.  The file is opened using `new StreamWriter(File.Open("C:\\temp\\myLog.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));`  Any ideas?

```
public MyFormConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this._fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    this._fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
    this._fileSystemWatcher.Path = "C:\\temp\\";
    this._fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "myLog.txt";
    this._fileSystemWatcher.Changed += this.OnLogChanged;
    this._fileSystemWatcher.Created += this.OnLogChanged;
    this._fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += this.OnLogChanged;
    this._fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += this.OnLogChanged;
    this._fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnLogChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ChangeType) // <-- never gets here
    {
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
            this.UpdateLogView();
            break;
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
        case WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed:
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code works.  I put a debug stop on "never gets here", creating that file, and the code stopped.

Comment: Same here. How are you confirming that OnLogChanged() isn't being called?

Comment: I'm using a breakpoint to confirm.  Does it matter that the file is being updated by the same process?  I know the file is getting updated because I can open it in Notepad++ and see the updates.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That's unfortunate.  I know Notepad++ isn't C# (probably Win32 C++), but I wonder how they do it.  I'm not above invoking native methods. ;P

Comment: This is a filesystem object; it's monitoring the filesystem (no need to climb back up into the trees and resort to C++; same OS object). My copy of your code hits my breakpoint whether I update the file from the same process or another. Are those paths in your question the actual literal verbatim string values used in your source code, copied and not retyped?

Comment: I think Çöđěxěŕ had it right.  This file is not getting released, and I suspect it won't get released until the process exits because it's getting its updates from Trace statements tied to a `TextWriterTraceListener`.

Comment: Released by what? Can you show the code that writes to the file?

Comment: @EdPlunkett This is basically it: https://pastebin.com/0fJts5Fy
Then, any calls to `Trace.WriteLine` will send the string to both the VS Output window and the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the filesystem event when the StreamWriter is disposed, but not before.

So dispose it.

```
public class FlushingTextTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public FlushingTextTraceListener(string filePath)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
    }
    public String FilePath { get; set; }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            sw.Write(message);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```